# Tkinter use keyboard for 5 buttons without tab key

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, button, keyboard-events

I have 5 buttons in my GUI and I wanna use keyboard for pressing them. It needes to press tab key to move the focus from one button to another.
I want to have a code that can focus all buttons with each other ; for example when I press "a" first button goes on and after that I press "b" second button goes on.
my code needs the tab key to be pressed between "a" and "b", how can we do this without "tab".
here is one of my buttons code:

```
start=0  
start1 = Label(win,   text = "Start Manual",     fg = "#cbcbcb",     font = ("Helvetica", 10 , "bold"), background = '#2d3d4f')
start1.pack(pady = 5)


def Switch1(event):
    global start
      
    if start==1:
        button_start1.config(image = off1 ,  background = '#2d3d4f'  )
        start1.config(text = "Start Manual",  background = '#2d3d4f'   ,   fg = "#cbcbcb")
        start=0
    elif start==0 :
        
        button_start1.config(image = on1,  background = '#2d3d4f'  )
        start1.config(text = "Start Auto", fg = "#b4f9a5", background = '#2d3d4f')
        start=1
              
on1 = PhotoImage(file = "on1.png")
off1 = PhotoImage(file = "off1.png")
  
button_start1 = Button(win, image = off1,  background = '#2d3d4f'  , bd = 0)

button_start1.focus_set()
button_start1.bind("<a>" , Switch1)
button_start1.bind("<Button-1>" , Switch1)
button_start1.pack(pady = 5)

start1.place (x=1250 , y =105)
button_start1 . place (x=1260 , y=50)
```

Comment: I don't understand what you are saying, if you want to make something happen when a key is pressed you do `root.bind(keycode, function)`

Comment: I do this exactly : button_start1.bind("<a>" , Switch1). I have 5 buttons, when I run the code the focus is just on the first button , and when I press "a" the first button goes to "on" state, but when I press "b" that is for second button nothing happens ; when I press tab key the focus goes on second button and it works right when I press "b"...   I want to press "b" at first ,that is for second button, without tab key...

Comment: you need to do `root.bind` not `button_start1.bind` doing root instead means that only the window needs to be focused instead of the specific button, if you want to run code to focus a specific button you can do `button_start1.focus()`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.